# Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 158 : {LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

When I send data to topic "my-topic" all is good.
As soon as I try to send same data to "my-11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111-topic" I get
[Producer clientId=producer-2] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 158 : {my-11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

I wan't to send every file in separate topic with file's uuid in topic name.

I've already tried:

listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

But it didn't help

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you creating `my-topic` in advance ? Do you have the `auto.create.topics.enable` setting in your broker config ?

Comment: It's true by default. The problems are occurred only when I send to topic with uuid in name.

Answer (score 0):

your problem might be that you haven't created the topic when you run the consumer. without a topic, you can't engage with a topic. before you run the consumer please create the topic and try again.